# Reverse engineering tool for java that does many to many

Tags: java, jdbc, entity, reverse

I am trying several java tools that generate entities from tables. I have tried netbeans one and eclipse tools from oracle (OEPE).

I see that they fails to recognize many to many relationships. 
How can I improve this situation?

Thanks,
Mario

---

Ok I have also tried hibernate and no one detects the many to many. Probably the table misses something to be recognized.

Thanks to all,
Mario

Comment: Netbeans does recognize ManyToMany relations for me...

Comment: Whats the ORM technology in play here. Netbeans afaik generates many-to-many as bidirectional @OneToMany, which works perfectly from a JPA point of view.